# React-Select v2.0.0 history confusion?

Tags: react-select

Two months ago, React-Select V2.0.0 was released [npm React-Select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select).  I see this morning on their github it's showing V2.0.0 was re-released [React-Select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/releases).

I am confused whether new code was committed(seems like it based on the commit history).

Is this typical to not bump the version?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's just an error from the author as if you pay attention to the latest commits the v2.1.0 will be released soon.

[image: React-select commits]